# Linq Razor Script to an A - Z Index

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, razor

I have been trying to figure out the best approach to creating a script that is similar to the job listings on this page: http://www.usi.edu/careersv/jobsearch.asp. I have created the database and populated it but I am stuck at the most efficient method of getting my information to be displayed in any way close to what is on the page. My ideal look would be an A-Z hyperlink at the top and once the user clicks on a letter it displays below the horizontal lists what is available.

This is what I have done so far:

```
  @using admin.code.Database

    @{
       var car = new DatabaseEntities();
       var result = (from item in table.Lists                  
              orderby item.Name ascending 
              select item);

 foreach (var res in result)
{
   <div>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="@res.Link">@res.Name</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
}
```

}

Could I get some advice on a more efficient direction to move in?

Answer (score 1):

Group by the first letter, then loop through the group to display.

something along the lines of this:

```
var result = table.Lists.OrderBy(x => x.Name).GroupBy(x => x.Name[0])
```

Display:

```
foreach(var res in result)
{
    <a href="#@res.Key"></a>

    foreach(var item in res.Where(x => x[0] == res.Key){
        <div>
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="@item.Link">@item.Name</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
    }
}
```

Make sure you don't have empty strings or handle that case on the character lookup.

Answer (score 0):

```
char[] alpha = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray();

var car = new DatabaseEntities();
var result = table.Lists.OrderBy(l=>l.Name); // For displaying them all
var groups=result.GroupBy(l=>l.Substring(0,1)).OrderBy(l=>l.Key);
var hasAlpha=groups.Select(l=>l.key);

<ul>
foreach(var letter in alpha)
{
if (hasAlpha.Contains(letter.toString())
{
<li>@letter.toString()</li>

} else {
<li><a href="#@letter.toString()">@letter.ToString()</a></li>
}
</ul>

foreach(var group in groups)
{
<ul id="#@group.Key">
foreach(var item in group)
{
<li>@item.Name</li>
}
</ul>
}
```

Comment: That should dump out all letters, including disabled ones, then also generate the stuff at the bottom, grouped by first letter, and the target of the hyperlink.  Or pretty close anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start from the key values (that is: the tab names) and build the query from there:

```
var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".Cast<string>();

var tabs =
  from letter in letters
  select new {
    Key = letter,
    Items =
      from item in tables.Lists
      where item.Name.StartsWith(letter, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
      select item
  };

<ul id="navLinks">
foreach (var tab in tabs) {
  <li>
    <a class="navLink" href="#@tab.Key">
      @tab.Key
    </a>
  </li>
}
</ul>

<div id="items">
  foreach (var tab in tabs) {
    <ul id="@tab.Key" class="tab">
      foreach (var item in tab.Items) {
        <li class="tabItem">
          @item.Name
        </li>
      }
    </ul>
  }
</div>
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I value code clarity over performance.

Comment: Can i have an example of adding a ul and li?

Comment: @Paradigm: The (untested) code sample above should now match the USI page pretty closely.